# How to tell the results of git commit before git push?

Tags: git

I'm new to git.  I understand that once I add new files using `git add`, I have to run `git commit` and then `git push`.

The other day, I did this and was surprised to find out that not all of my files were checked in, so I would like to ask the following question:

Once I do `git commit`, how can I tell for sure exactly what is going to be checked in before I do `git push`?  Can I make a copy of my project, as it will be pushed to git?

Answer (score 7):

If you run `git status` before `git commit` it will tell you which changes will be included in the commit and which won't.

Once you've run `git commit` the changes are already checked in to your local repository. Pushing does not check them in, it just updates another repository with the commits you have in your local repository. This is different from a centralised VCS like Subversion.

Before you push there are several ways of seeing what will be pushed:

- `git diff origin/master` will show the differences between your current state and `origin/master`.
- `git log origin/master..master` will list the commits that will be pushed, but not show you their contents.

Comment: @Abizem: the statement "not all of my files were checked in" suggests that the question is in fact "why weren't some local files included in my commit" and if that's the case then `git status` would be a very helpful command here.

Answer (score 4):

```
git show
```

will show the details of the commit last commit.

If there were more than one commit you can also use

```
git diff origin/master
```

assuming your remote is named `origin` and the branch you want to push to is `master`.

Comment: Remember to `git fetch` first!

Answer (score 2):

1. `git diff` will give you a good handle on the changes you are making. For example, you can use `git diff origin/master` (if the remote you are pushing to is named origin) to see the differences between your current branch and your remote.
2. Another way of going at this is to use `git show`. If you've made 3 commits locally, you can use `git show HEAD...HEAD~3` to see the contents of your last three commits.
3. A more complex (but easily aliasable) means is to use `whatchanged`:

   `git whatchanged -p --abbrev-commit --pretty=medium`

   I use a git alias fill where this is assigned to `gwc` in my shell.

Comment: I think perhaps you misunderstood the question. I'm asking how to tell what's being committed *after* `git commit` and *before* `git push`

Comment: be sure to do a `git fetch` first to make sure that the local copy is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I use an alias to a bash script for this:

I keep the script below at `~/bin/git-outgoing` directory in my home directory.  My `~/bin/` is in my `PATH`; make sure wherever you put this is accessible if you plan to alias it.

**git-outgoing**:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Usage: git-outgoing [<upstream>] [<head> [<limit>]]
# Show commits on current branch that do not exist on branch <upstream>.

# bail out with message to stderr and exit status 1
die() {
    echo "$(basename $0):" "$@" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

# colors
SHA=$(git config --get-color 'color.branch.local')
ADD=$(git config --get-color 'color.diff.new')
REM=$(git config --get-color 'color.diff.old')
RESET=$(git config --get-color '' 'reset')

# get the current branch in refs/heads/<branch> form
ref=$(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD)
test -n "$ref" ||
die "you're not on a branch"

# just the branch name please
branch=$(echo "$ref" | sed 's@^refs/heads/@@')
test -n "$branch" ||
die "you're in a weird place; get on a local branch"

# use tracking branch if no upstream given
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    remote=$(git config --get "branch.$branch.remote" || true)

    merge=$(git config branch.$branch.merge) ||
    die "branch $branch isn't tracking a remote branch and no <upstream> given"

    set -- "$remote/$(echo "$merge" |sed 's@^refs/heads/@@')"
fi

git cherry -v "$@"                                |
cut -c1-9,43-                                     |
sed -e "s/^\(.\) \(.......\)/\1 $SHA\2$RESET/"    |
sed -e "s/^-/$REM-$RESET/" -e "s/^+/$ADD+$RESET/"
```

And this accompanying inbound script goes in `~/bin/git-incoming`:

**git-incoming**:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Usage: git-incoming [--diff] [<upstream>] [<head> [<limit>]]
# Show commits on <upstream> that do not exist on current branch.

# bail out with message to stderr and exit status 1
die() {
    echo "$(basename $0):" "$@" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

# colors
SHA=$(git config --get-color 'color.branch.local')
ADD=$(git config --get-color 'color.diff.new')
REM=$(git config --get-color 'color.diff.old')
RESET=$(git config --get-color '' 'reset')

# check for -d / --diff argument
diff=false
if [ "$1" = '-d' -o "$1" = '--diff' ]
then diff=true
     shift
fi

# use tracking branch if no upstream given
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    # get the current branch in refs/heads/<branch> form
    ref=$(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD)
    test -n "$ref" ||
    die "you're not on a branch"

    # just the branch name please
    branch=$(echo "$ref" | sed 's@^refs/heads/@@')
    test -n "$branch" ||
    die "you're in a weird place; get on a local branch"

    # grab remote name for current branch
    remote=$(git config --get "branch.$branch.remote" || true)

    # grab tracked branch name for current branch
    merge=$(git config branch.$branch.merge) ||
    die "branch $branch isn't tracking a remote branch and no <upstream> given"

    # make it so
    set -- "$remote/$(echo "$merge" |sed 's@^refs/heads/@@')"
fi

if $diff
then git diff HEAD..."$1"
else
     git cherry -v HEAD "$@"                           |
     cut -c1-9,43-                                     |
     sed -e "s/^\(.\) \(.......\)/\1 $SHA\2$RESET/"    |
     sed -e "s/^-/$REM-$RESET/" -e "s/^+/$ADD+$RESET/"
fi
```

In my `.gitconfig`, I create an alias to it like this:

```
[alias]
out = !git-outgoing
in = !git-incoming
```

Now I can just do `git out` in my project root to see what will be pushed, or `git in` to see what will be pulled.

These are scripts I found that were better than my own.  I cannot find the author but will edit that in when I do.

Answer (score 0):

You can go about it several ways, but the easiest is to use `git log --stat`.  It will show you a summary of the files that changed:

```
$ git log -2 --stat
commit 85318f521f6c0b9843d6da12abf67f2de7608431
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 26 15:10:17 2013 -0700

    Update draft release notes to 1.8.4

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>

 Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.txt | 12 ++++++++++++
 1 file changed, 12 insertions(+)

commit ad76feb55eb7645661421e213796129efcbb7d56
Merge: 12dd2f6 212eb96
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 26 15:08:09 2013 -0700

    Merge branch 'tr/maint-apply-non-git-patch-parsefix'

    Fix for the codepath to parse patches that add new files, generated
    by programs other than Git.  THis is an old breakage in v1.7.11 and
    will need to be merged down to the maintanance tracks.

    * tr/maint-apply-non-git-patch-parsefix:
      apply: carefully strdup a possibly-NULL name
```

This is an example from the git repository.  Note: merge commits won't show anything by default.  If you want to see stats on them, you need to pass the `--cc` option (which stands for "compact combined"):

```
$ git log -2 --stat --cc
commit 85318f521f6c0b9843d6da12abf67f2de7608431
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 26 15:10:17 2013 -0700

    Update draft release notes to 1.8.4

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>

 Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.txt | 12 ++++++++++++
 1 file changed, 12 insertions(+)

commit ad76feb55eb7645661421e213796129efcbb7d56
Merge: 12dd2f6 212eb96
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 26 15:08:09 2013 -0700

    Merge branch 'tr/maint-apply-non-git-patch-parsefix'

    Fix for the codepath to parse patches that add new files, generated
    by programs other than Git.  THis is an old breakage in v1.7.11 and
    will need to be merged down to the maintanance tracks.

    * tr/maint-apply-non-git-patch-parsefix:
      apply: carefully strdup a possibly-NULL name

 builtin/apply.c         |  2 +-
 t/t4111-apply-subdir.sh | 14 ++++++++++++++
 2 files changed, 15 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

To see the actual content that changed, you can use the `-p` option on `git log`, or look at the commit directly with `git show COMMIT_ID`.  I prefer the latter.  `git show` accepts the `--stat` option as well.

Answer (score 0):

Launch `gitk` or any other visual history browser: it shows your branch and the origin, the diff in the commits, and provide all the other tools to make a post-hoc review.